Trying to find air crash for a case study
trying to find a case study of an air crash that has some factor to do with generational differences.
I remember once crash where the FO just watch the aircraft go below G/S and crash and didn't say anything to not offend the captain.
Any help finding this crash or anything like it?

What about the Tenerife accident?

Could it be https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alitalia_Flight_404 ? In the English Wiki it is a bit less explicit, but the German wiki mentions how the conflict between the experienced pilot (47 years old) and the inexperienced FO (28 years old) caused the warnings from the FO to be ignored by the captain.

It's usually not phrased as "generational differences" but if you look around for crashes where poor crew resource management ("CRM") is noted as a cause, you should be on the right track to find this kind of accident report, especially ones that talk about a steep "authority gradient" (meaning the pilot in command is extremely senior/respected and domineering over a copilot who feels he can't speak up or call out the PIC's mistakes).

So, you have hypothesis but cannot find any proof supporting it? Maybe your hypotesis is wrong if you have to search with little luck and you are only getting far-fetched evidences?
Most of the list is CRM, not 'generation' driven. Like in case of that Korean flight - both pilots were same age, what was the root cause was not about generational differences.
&

That can be the accident of Korean Air 801 in 1997. However the captain was 42, the first officer 40 and the flight engineer 57.
The captain with a high reputation gained while landing an aircraft with an engine failure at low altitude was "Pilot Flying". He was approaching Guam airport runway that had its ILS out. The ILS receiver picked a wrong unrelated electronic signal on the ILS frequency. This signal guided the aircraft on the wrong approach path.
The first officer and the flight engineer realized the slope was obviously too steep to be the correct glidepath, the runway was not in sight, and heard the ground proximity warning, but none of them did dare to stop the captain. The aircraft crashed killing most of the people onboard.
The accident investigation noticed the captain error, but also the lack of appropriate reaction from the other crew members. This accident, following other ones like the Tenerife deadly collision, led to improve Crew Resource Management (CRM). CRM is aimed to create a the appropriate interpersonal relationship "for gaining and maintaining situational awareness, for solving problems and for making decisions."
From the NTSB report:

The first officer and flight engineer noted the ground proximity warning system (GPWS) callouts and the first officer properly called for a missed approach, but the captain’s failure to react properly to the GPWS minimums callout and the direct challenge from the first officer precluded action that might have prevented the accident.


The first officer and flight engineer failed to properly monitor and/or challenge the captain’s performance, which was causal to the accident.


The FAA also stated that, on February 25, 1997, it issued a revision (Change 2) to AC-120-51B [...] that the training should emphasize prevention through effective communication and decision behavior and the importance of immediate, decisive, and correct response to a ground proximity warning.


According to the FAA, paragraph 2(m) reiterates that training should emphasize the importance of recognizing each pilot’s relative experience level, experience in specific duty positions, preparation level, planning level, normal communication style and level, overload state, and fatigue state.


On a more general standpoint, these accidents are relative to a non assertive action from the pilot not flying:

Jetstream into Hibbing, MN, (NTSB, 1994a);
DC-8 into Jeddah, Saudi Arabia (NTSB, 1993a);
C99 into Anniston, AL, (NTSB, 1993b);
Beechjet into Rome, GA, (NTSB, 1992a);
DC-8 loss of control at Toledo, OH, (NTSB, 1992b);
707 fuel exhaustion into JFK, Washington DC, (NTSB, 1991);
L-1011 windshear accident, D/FW Airport, TX, (NTSB, 1986);
MS-748 electrical failure in Pinckneyville, IL (NTSB, 1985);
737 out of Washington National, Washington DC, (NTSB, 1982);
DC-8 fuel exhaustion in Portland, OR, (NTSB, 1979);
727 into Dulles New York City, NY, (NTSB, 1975);
DC-8 freighter into Cold Bay, AK, (NTSB, 1974);
Convair into New Haven, CT, (NTSB, 1972);
L-188 into a thunderstorm at Dawson, TX, (NTSB, 1969);
Lear Jet out of Palm Springs, CA, (NTSB, 1967);
F-27 into Las Vegas, NV, (CAB, 1965).

From TO INTERVENE OR NOT TO INTERVENE? THE CO-PILOT'S CATCH 22

East Asian crews are notorious for not daring to question the captain's decisions, but this is a cultural issue rather than a generational one.
